# HttpPost - Sending image and text with Multipart - Error

Tags: android, http-post, mime-types, multipartform-data, multipartentity

I am sending image and text to server using Multi part.
I am getting error as I need to send empty string in one parameter like:

```
HashMap<String, String> Map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map.put("course_id",  "");
```

In Asynctask,

```
MultipartEntity reqEntity = null;
StringBody course_id = null;
course_id = new StringBody(map.get("course_id"));
reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("course_id", course_id );
```

Here it is throwing exception and response is in HTML.
My requirement is to send empty string and whenever I send empty string it throws exception so how would I send empty string?

ERROR :

```
 <!doctype html>
                                                          <html lang='en'>
                                                          <head>
                                                              <meta charset='UTF-8'>
                                                              <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
                                                              <title>Wrong turn!</title>
                                                              <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                                                              <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://images.qourier.com/imgs/images/favicon.ico">
                                                              <link rel="apple-itouch-icon" href="http://images.com/imgs/images/favicon.png">
                                                          </head>
                                                          <style>

   org.json.JSONException: Value <!doctype of type java.lang.String cannot     be converted to JSONObject
   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the error you get? post your logcat

Comment: @SaravInfern it shows html response. I tried to add headers but then also it is not working.

Comment: Please add error log.

Comment: @SaravInfern pls check

Comment: @MayurPatel pls check

Comment: hey it's servers error. may be service side coding has some issue. tell your php developer html is there in response.

Comment: @DäñishShärmà but if I add Map.put("course_id",  "abcd"); like this then it is working fine as my requirement is to send Map.put("course_id",  ""); like this.

Comment: @BansiDoshi the issue is with server, the server is not responsing to your parameters. Please check with your server coding

Comment: can't say anything about this but you should tell thing to your backend developer because if you do anything wrong it should throw the exception not html.

Comment: @DäñishShärmà Yes they are saying that add request headers i added two headers : HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setEntity(multipart);
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");